# Error creating custom plugin Vuejs + Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, plugins, vuejs2

I have this structure of my index and service plugin:

[image]

service.ts

```
declare interface Params {
  title: string;
  description?: string;
  type?: string;
  duration?: number;
}

export default class ServiceToast {
  public toastRef: any; // component

  public constructor(modalRef: any) {
    this.toastRef = modalRef;
    console.log(this.toastRef);
  }

  public open(params: Params) {
    this.toastRef.open(params);
  }
}
```

Basically I have created a service that receives the component so that it interacts with the component at ease.

index.ts:

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Toast from '@/components/_includes/layouts/Toast.vue';
import ServiceToast from './service';

const ToastPlugin = {
  install: (Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any) => {
    Vue.mixin({
      created() {
        Vue.prototype.$toast = new ServiceToast(Toast);
      },
    });
  },
};

export default ToastPlugin;
```

Where I install the plugin and use the service that I showed above.

[image]

Here I call the plugin and make it the corresponding Vue.use but when I want to call it in any component:

```
<a @click="$toast.open({ title: 'Hola mundo' })">Hola, dame click!</a>
```

I get the following error: "TypeError: this.toastRef.open is not a function"

En el shims-vue-plugin.d.ts:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import Vue from 'vue';
import { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import 'webpack-env';
import { FieldFlagsBag } from 'vee-validate';
import { SnackbarProgrammatic as Snackbar, DialogProgrammatic as Dialog } from 'buefy';
import ServiceToast from './app-config/toast/service';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $auth: any;
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
    veeFields: FieldFlagsBag;
    $dialog: typeof Dialog;
    $snackbar: typeof Snackbar;
    $toast: ServiceToast;
  }
}


declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Process extends __WebpackModuleApi.NodeProcess {
    server: boolean;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what it could be? or that I'm missing since I can't find the error: /

Comment: @PeiroPajares did you check in the console what is value of `this.$toast`? I am not sure what are you importing `import Toast from '@/components/_includes/layouts/Toast.vue'`? Would you be able to share github/codesandbox project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.$toast` in any component is not going to be an instance of `Toast.vue`. It's the export. To have an actual instance you need to `$mount()` it:

```
import _Vue from 'vue'; 

// create a class
const ToastClass = _Vue.extend(this.$toast.toastRef);

// get an instance of the class
const instance = new ToastClass();

// mount it
instance.$mount();
// now you have an instance, so you can call any of its methods, i.e: 
// instance.open();
// but it's not yet appended to DOM. to append it to the current component:

this.$el.appendChild(instance.$el);
```

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve but, at first glance, having an instance of a component in every single one of your app's components doesn't seem like a good idea. Each toast instance will also have a `this.$toast`. Toast-ception :)

You're probably better off having an array of toasts in `$store` and a container appended to your app's root element, with a plain

```
<toast v-for="toast in toasts" />
```

When a toast expires, commit and remove it from state.
When you want to add another, just push a new one.

Answer (score 1):

From tao's solution it remains this way.

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Toast from '../../components/_includes/layouts/Toast.vue';
import ServiceToast from './service';

export default {
  install: (Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any) => {
    const toastComponent = new Toast();
    Vue.mixin({
      created() {
        Vue.prototype.$toast = new ServiceToast(toastComponent);
      },
      mounted() {
        const el = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.append(el);
        toastComponent.$mount(el);
      },
    });
  },
};
```

works properly now :)